# Как генерировать последовательность вида «0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3...» в Prolog?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

Надо генерировать элементы такой вот последовательности "0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3...". Дошел только до этого, но результат крашится:

```
num(1).
num(X) :- num(Y), X is -Y, X < 0.
num(X) :- num(Y), X is -Y + 1, X > 0.
```

вывод:

```
?- num(X).
X = 1 ;
X = -1 ;
ERROR: Out of local stack
  Exception: (1,763,389) num(_6002) ?
```

Прошу помощи, люди добрые.

Answer (score 0):

Такая функция выведет массив элементов (0, 1, -1...)

```
 insert(Item, List, [Item|List]).

 num_(Index, MaxIndex, ResultList) :- Index = MaxIndex, ResultList is [Index], !.
 num_(Index, MaxIndex, ResultList) :- Index > 0, NewIndex is (0 - Index), num_(NewIndex, MaxIndex, ResList), insert(Index,ResList, ResultList).
 num_(Index, MaxIndex, ResultList) :- Index =< 0, NewIndex is (0 - Index + 1 ), num_(NewIndex, MaxIndex, ResList), insert(Index,ResList, ResultList).

 num_(MaxIndex, Result) :- num_(0, MaxIndex, Result).
```

Comment: Запускать нужно так: `num_(10, X)` - дойти до 10ти, результат возвращается в X

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень помог, но вопрос все же, что у меня не так в коде?

Comment: Мне кажется, что он никогда не останавливается